# How to make multiple catalogs on one site using a common vocabulary?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have 4 node types:

- Type 1
- Type 2
- Type 3
- Type 4

There are also 3 vocabularies (taxonomy)

- Vocabulary 1
- Vocabulary 2
- Vocabulary 3

Each type of material has many of own fields, but these 3 vocabularies (Vocabulary 1, Vocabulary 2 and Vocabulary 3) are common to each of these 4 types of material.
Each of the vocabularies contains several hundred terms. Also vocabularies have their own set of fields.

If the type of material and the catalog would be one, then of course everything is obvious. View `taxonomy/term/%`, once configure pathauto for vocabulary terms (type-1/term-name), metatag for vocabularies, titles, etc. But how to be when the are 4 types of nodes, and it is required to comply with the condition for taxonomy paths:

- type-1/term-name
- type-2/term-name
- type-3/term-name
- type-4/term-name

An example of how it should be:
Types of materials:

- News
- Event

Dictionary:

- Cities

Url should be of the form:

- news/city
- event/city

And also catalogs on terms:

- News
- Events

Accordingly, each of the directories when selecting a particular city should show only either the events of the selected city (if the event directory), or the news of its city (if the catalog is news). And also cities should be set up corresponding Meta either for events in cities, or for news in cities.

At first glance, it's need to create 4 sets of taxonomy vocabularies for each type of material, such as:

- Vocabulary 1 for material type 1
- Vocabulary 1 for material type 2
- Vocabulary 1 for material type 3
- Vocabulary 1 for material type 4
- Vocabulary 2 for material type 1
- Vocabulary 2 for material type 2
- Vocabulary 2 for material type 3
- Vocabulary 2 for material type 4
- Vocabulary 3 for material type 1
- Vocabulary 3 for material type 2
- Vocabulary 3 for material type 3
- Vocabulary 3 for material type 4

And then of course everything is configured in an obvious way. But in my case it's a wrong way to duplicate. After all, what if you had to make 10 node types with common vocabulary? Duplicate 10 vocabularies, and then synchronize them, if something is added to them?

What do you advise? How correctly to organize such?

Comment: Why do you need to duplicate vocabularies at all?

Comment: I don't need to duplicate. And I don't want duplicate vocabularies. But I don't know how to organize this structure without duplicates. So i'm searching the solution, how to do it right.